# How to convert a an unixtimestamp to a proper timestamp in logstash

Tags: logging, logstash

I would like to extract the timestamp from the entry coming in the format below (and possibly also the programm name). How would I convert this entry into a proper logstash timestamp? I guess this can be done via a filter, but i have only examples where strings where extracted, but how would i convert this entry back to a date time string?

```
[36931.604673] anacron[502]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
[36931.541637] anacron[502]: Job `cron.weekly' started
```

Answer (score 1):

The date filter can parse unix timestamps.

This would be the filter:

```
date {
        match => [ "message", "UNIX" ]
        target => "my_timestamp"
    }
```

Note:

Message will be the grok field you parse your timestamp to. The date filter will then come after.

I tested this with only the timestamp, and stdin/stdout gives:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf2/
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
36931.604673
{
         "message" => "36931.604673",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-08-08T12:15:41.538Z",
            "host" => "pandaadb",
    "my_timestamp" => "1970-01-01T10:15:31.604Z"
}
```

You can read your docs here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html

Artur